# Create an editable tkinter treeview with keyword connection

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-button

I want to create a tkinter treeview with editable feature so I have got a sample code from 'So' itself. But instead of Ok button I want my keyboard 'enter' button to save changes.
When I double click the element I can edit that but in addition to that if I press the enter button It should update the element instead of pressing ok button.
Here is the code.

```
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
columns = ("Items", "Values")
Treeview = ttk.Treeview(root, height=18, show="headings", columns=columns)  #
Treeview.column("Items", width=200, anchor='center')
Treeview.column("Values", width=200, anchor='center')
Treeview.heading("Items", text="Items")
Treeview.heading("Values", text="Values")
Treeview.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH)
name = ['Item1', 'Item2', 'Item3']
ipcode = ['10', '25', '163']
for i in range(min(len(name), len(ipcode))):
    Treeview.insert('', i, values=(name[i], ipcode[i]))
def treeview_sort_column(tv, col, reverse):
    l = [(tv.set(k, col), k) for k in tv.get_children('')]
    l.sort(reverse=reverse)
    for index, (val, k) in enumerate(l):
        tv.move(k, '', index)
        tv.heading(col, command=lambda: treeview_sort_column(tv, col, not reverse))
def set_cell_value(event):
    for item in Treeview.selection():
        item_text = Treeview.item(item, "values")
        column = Treeview.identify_column(event.x)
        row = Treeview.identify_row(event.y)
    cn = int(str(column).replace('#', ''))
    rn = int(str(row).replace('I', ''))
    entryedit = Text(root, width=10 + (cn - 1) * 16, height=1)
    entryedit.place(x=16 + (cn - 1) * 130, y=6 + rn * 20)
    def saveedit():
        Treeview.set(item, column=column, value=entryedit.get(0.0, "end"))
        entryedit.destroy()
        okb.destroy()
    okb = ttk.Button(root, text='OK', width=4, command=saveedit)
    okb.place(x=90 + (cn - 1) * 242, y=2 + rn * 20)
def newrow():
    name.append('to be named')
    ipcode.append('value')
    Treeview.insert('', len(name) - 1, values=(name[len(name) - 1], ipcode[len(name) - 1]))
    Treeview.update()
    newb.place(x=120, y=(len(name) - 1) * 20 + 45)
    newb.update()
Treeview.bind('<Double-1>', set_cell_value)
newb = ttk.Button(root, text='new item', width=20, command=newrow)
newb.place(x=120, y=(len(name) - 1) * 20 + 45)
for col in columns:
    Treeview.heading(col, text=col, command=lambda _col=col: treeview_sort_column(Treeview, _col, False))
root.mainloop()
```

Please help me resolve the issue, Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Why don't you use `Entry` instead of `Text` for a single line input box?

Comment: That would be nice but Does entry method accepts the enter command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind the event `<Return>` on the input box to execute `saveedit()` whenever the *Enter* key is pressed.

Also it is better to use `Entry` instead of `Text` if you just want a single line input box.

Below is the modified `set_cell_value()`:

```py
def set_cell_value(event):
    def saveedit(event):
        Treeview.set(row, column=column, value=event.widget.get())
        event.widget.destroy()

    row = Treeview.identify_row(event.y)
    column = Treeview.identify_column(event.x)
    item_text = Treeview.set(row, column)
    x, y, w, h = Treeview.bbox(row, column)
    entryedit = Entry(root)
    entryedit.place(x=x, y=y, width=w, height=h)
    entryedit.insert("end", item_text)
    entryedit.bind("<Return>", saveedit)
    entryedit.focus_set()
    entryedit.grab_set()  # don't let user double-click other cell
```

Comment: Thanyou so much mr @acw1668 It resolved the issue. It was nice intaracting with you.

Comment: I have accepted your answer cannot upvote your answer  as I need to have atleast 15 reputations and I have only 11